# Yii2: Updating Grid-view using Pjax

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, pjax

Following this Wiki [Yii 2.0: Pjax on ActiveForm and GridView - Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/772/pjax-on-activeform-and-gridview-yii2/)

I have tried to use my gridview to update on Ajax without page-reload, but couldn't succeed.

**code of my _form.php**

```
<?php

$this->registerJs(
   '$("document").ready(function(){ 
        $("#new_medicine").on("pjax:end", function() {
            $.pjax.reload({container:"#medicine"});  //Reload GridView
        });
    });'
);
?>


<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
//use yii\grid\Gridview;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Medicine */
/* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
?>
<!-- <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3"> -->
<div class="medicine-form">
    <?php yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['id' => 'new_medicine']) ?>

     <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['data-pjax' => true ]]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'medicine_id')->textInput(['maxlength' => 10]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'medicine_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => 50]) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Save & New' : '',$option=['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary','name'=>'save_and_new']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
    <?php yii\widgets\Pjax::end() ?>

</div>
```

**Code in my controller**

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model = new Medicine();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save())
        {
            $model = new Medicine(); //reset model
        }
        $searchModel = new MedicineSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

**code in index.php**

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\MedicineSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Medicines';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="medicine-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create Medicine', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::begin(['id' => 'medicine']); ?>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'id',
            'medicine_id',
            'medicine_name',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
<?php \yii\widgets\Pjax::end(); ?>
</div>
```

I think I have followed the instructions very carefully, but surely I am missing something as the grid-view is not showing the new records added without page-reload.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that ajax is not working? I mean do you check the firebug and you don't see any ajax request?

Comment: Hi Dear Ali, Yes it's not working. only difference from the wiki is that I have not rendered the form on the `index.php page`. I want to update the grid-view from the `_form.php`. If I am rendering the form on the index.php then it is working, but that doesn't solve my purpose.

Comment: I am adding data in the _form.php itself and I have kept the index.php page open in other browser tab. I want to see the data update in the index page(grid-view) page. is that not possible?

Comment: Hi Ali, real purpose I am trying to accomplish is that I have a medicine request form and there is a grid-view under medicine-store with the same data. The medicine store will know without page refresh that there is a new medicine request.

Answer (score 5):

try to explain how to do it as a widget; it's a generic solution, so contact me in case of troubles:

Controller (@your-alias/controllers/yourController):

```
...
public function actionManage($param=''){
    $model = new YourModel();

    if (Yii::$app->request->isPjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save())
    {
        $model = new YourModel(); //reset model
    }
    $model->paramId = $param;
    $queryParams = Yii::$app->request->getQueryParams();
    $queryParams['YourModelSearch']['param'] = $param;
    $searchModel = new YourModelSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search($queryParams);

    return $this->renderAjax('@your-alias/widgets/views/index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}...
```

widgets (@your-alias/widgets/) [form, view]:

_form:

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;

/**
 * @var yii\web\View $this
 * @var yourModule/models/YourModel $model
 * @var yii\widgets\ActiveForm $form
 */
?>
<?php
$js = <<<JS
// get the form id and set the event
$('form#{$model->formName()}').on('beforeSubmit', function(e) {
   var \$form = $(this);
   // do whatever here, see the parameter \$form? is a jQuery Element to your form
    console.log(\$form);
    console.log("MODEL CODE = " + $("#yourmodel-code").val());
}).on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
JS;
//$this->registerJs($js);
$this->registerJs(
   '$("#new-your-model").on("pjax:end", function() {
        commonLib.divAction("#div_new_model", "hide"); //hide form
        $.pjax.reload({container:"#models"});  //Reload GridView
    });', \yii\web\View::POS_READY
);
?>

<div class="model-form">

    <?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'new-model', 'timeout' => false, 'enablePushState' => false]) ?>
        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'id' => $model->formName(),
            //'method' => 'post',
            'action' => ['/module/controller/manage?param='.$model->code],
            'options' => ['data-pjax' => true ],
            //'layout' => 'default',
            ]); ?>

        <?= $form->field($model, 'code')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255]) ?>

        ...


        <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        </div>

        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
    <?php yii\widgets\Pjax::end() ?>

</div>
```

index view (grid view):

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;

/**
 * @var yii\web\View $this
 * @var yii\data\ActiveDataProvider $dataProvider
 * @var yourModule\models\search\YourModelSearch $searchModel
 */
?>
<div class="model-index">

    <!--h1><!--?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1-->

    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <p>


        <?= Html::button(Yii::t('bp', 'Add ...'), [
            'class' => 'btn btn-success',
            'onclick'=>'js:commonLib.divAction("#div_new_model", "show")'
        ])?>
    </p>

    <div id="div_new_model" style="display:none">
        <?= Html::button(Yii::t('common', 'Cancel'), [
            'class' => 'btn btn-success',
            'onclick'=>'js:commonLib.divAction("#div_new_model", "hide")'
        ])?>

        <!-- Render create form -->
        <?= $this->render('_formModel', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]) ?>
    </div>

<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'models', 'timeout' => false, 'enablePushState' => false]) ?>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            ...

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end() ?>
</div>
```

widget call (in view):

```
echo @your-alias\widgets\YourWidget::widget([
'param' => $model->param,]);
```

Answer (score 3):

`$.pjax.reload('#my-grid-pjax' , {timeout : false});`

Answer (score 2):

To update `GridView` table without page reload using pjax:

```
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;

Pjax::begin(['id' => 'todaysactivity', 'timeout' => false, 'enablePushState' => false])
```

Use jQuery/JavaScript as follows:

```
var url = baseurl + '/activity/logging'; // url where the gridview table need to update
$.pjax.reload({container: "#todaysactivity", url: url}); // refresh the grid
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a suitable solution to update the grid-view widget using pjax.
I resolved by using a auto-refresh method for the grid-view page. I understand that this is not the best solution and I am still looking for a suitable solution.

The method I have used is like this:

```
<script>
function autoRefresh()
{
   window.location.reload();
}

setInterval('autoRefresh()', 60000); // this will reload page after every 1 minute.
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.pjax.defaults.timeout = false;
</script>
```

The default pjax timeout setting doesn't give the page time to do anything so it reloads.

[Reference](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax#pjax-options)