# yii2: update/refresh/reload a page using Pjax different from requesting page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

I have asked this question, but I think that wasn't clear enough so I am putting it differently. I have a _form.php page and a grid-view(index.php)page.

I am sending a Pjax request from _form.php and want to update/refresh the grid-view(index.php)page.

on top my _form.php I am having this code.

```
<?php

    $this->registerJs(
       '$("document").ready(function(){ 
            $("#new_medicine").on("pjax:end", function() {
                $.pjax.reload({container:"#medicine"});  //Reload GridView
            });
        });'
    );
    ?>
```

Now the container `"#medicine"` is not on _form.php page, but grid-view(index.php) page. So how can I modify the above code so that it updates/refresh the container `"#medicine"` in index.php page.

I think I have explained the situation correctly. please tell me, if more information is needed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `$this::POS_READY` instead of wrapping your code in `$("document").ready(function(){})`

```
$js = '$("#new_medicine").on("pjax:end", function() {
           $.pjax.reload({container:"#medicine"});  //Reload GridView
       });'

$this->registerJs($js, $this::POS_READY);
```

**EDIT**

Apparently you want to reload the gridview that is open on another client's `index.php` after data is inserted using `_form.php`.

It isn't possible to send jQuery commands to another client (browser) and have it executed.

You can for example reload the gridview on the `index.php` every x seconds or minutes.

```
 $js = 'function refresh() {
     $.pjax.reload({container:"#medicine"});
     setTimeout(refresh, 5000); // restart the function every 5 seconds
 }
 refresh();';
 $this->registerJs($js, $this::POS_READY);
```

Comment: Hi deacs, thanks for your suggestion. But the real problem as per my question is `({container:"#medicine"})` the div with id #`medicine` is on index.php and not _form.php, so what is the syntax for refreshing/reload div on other page index.php

Comment: is your _form.php partially rendered into index.php? in other words: does the form and the gridview appear on the same page?

Comment: No, both are completely separate pages.

Comment: Then the question doesn't really make sense. Pjax is meant to manipulate the contents of a container on a page that you're on. You can't really manipulate a page that hasn't been loaded yet right?

Comment: Thnaks deacs, I though it can be done that way. Can you point me, if there are any option to achieve an update on grid-view page on data insert from _form.php.

Comment: But if you submit data into the form on _form.php (actionCreate/actionUpdate) and then navigate to the index.php (actionIndex) then it will be updated.

Comment: You are right. but I am giving you a use case - data is entered in medicine_request form to medicine store. now at another location medicine store has grid-view page kept open in his browser. medicine store is not navigating anywhere. That gridview page needs to show the updated request without page refresh. Can this be done?

Comment: Well it can't be done with jquery from where the data is entered. You should. You could make a loop on index.php that reloads the grid-view every x seconds. I will update my answer.

Comment: Ok, I had that solution partly [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777512/yii2-updating-grid-view-using-pjax[link]. But your solution is better and I accept it, but I am looking for a solution I have read somewhere like `"server-sent-event"` may be that is too complex to implement

Comment: you're going to need something discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet which is quite complex, but very fun to learn!

Comment: Thanks deacs for the link