# Pjax reload in pjax:complete

Tags: javascript, yii2, pjax

I am trying to reload `alerts` container after a pjax request.
What I am aiming for is a code that will reload the container after any pjax request has been made, so I don't have to individually call it every time.

I have the following code:

```
$(document).on('pjax:complete', function(event) {
        $.pjax.reload({container:"#alerts"});
});
```

However, this sends the whole page into a never ending loop.

Is there a way to make this work or should I not use pjax for this particular problem?

Thank you very much.

**Update**
The following code works, but I feel it is not the perfect solution:

```
var time = Date.now();
$(document).on(\'pjax:complete\' , function(event) {
    if(time <= Date.now()){ //Check if there has been a recent reload
        time = Date.now() + 1000;
        console.log(time);
        App.restartGlobalFunction();
        $.pjax.reload({container:"#alerts", async:false});
    }
});
```

Comment: See this answer too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777512/yii2-updating-grid-view-using-pjax/28868264#28868264 you'll need to set the timeout as well else it won't work.

Comment: I've updated the question. Quite the opposite worked.

Answer (score 5):

try pjax on particular id of Pjax Widget as:-

```
$this->registerJs('
    jQuery(document).on("pjax:success", "#brand-form",  function(event){
            $.pjax.reload({container:"#alerts",timeout:2e3})
          }
        );
   ');
```

Comment: Well, then it works only on that particular widget right?
What I am trying to do is have the above code work on any pjax call.

Thank you for the answer.

Comment: It will create a pjax never ending loop since $.pjax.reload is also a PJAX call which will again call `pjax:complete` ..

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be taking a URL pjax container to add the option `location` to taking containers. if you page many one pjax to need to add pjax `id` and `location`