# YII2. How auto update (periodically) column in GridView?

Tags: ajax, gridview, yii2, pjax

I try to update some column periodically (5 sec.) in GridView-widget, but this update all page

**View**

```
<?php
$script = <<< JS
$(module).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {     
      $.pjax.reload({container:'#state-dependence'});
    }, 5000); 
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>

<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
    <?= GridView::widget([ 'id'=>'module',
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'layout' => '{items}',
        'tableOptions' => ['class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered'],
        'columns' => [
             'Id', 
             'Title',
             [ 
               'format' => 'raw',
               'value' => function ($model) {
                return Html::tag('span', Html::encode($model::GetStringState($model->State)), 
                                ['id' => 'state-dependence']);
               }
             ],
             [ 
               'format' => 'raw',
               'value' => function ($model) {
                return Html::tag('span', Html::encode($model->Value), 
                                ['id' => 'state-dependence']);
               }
             ]

        ],
    ]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

How to get updated only some columns without reloading all page? Is there a right way?

Comment: You've got two ids of 'state-dependence', and it's probably confusing as id's are supposed to be unique to each element. Try renaming one of them and see if it works then.

Comment: I tested with 1 row with 1 column with a unique Id. The result is the same - the page is reloaded completely.

Comment: Ok,we've eliminated that then! One more question, what's the module in $(module).ready(function() for? Usually that would be $(document).ready(function()

Comment: Also, have you checked that pjax is requesting the correct urls, and that no errors are being thrown?

Comment: 'module' - it is yii2 classs GridView. (in html its a div)

Comment: I havn`t any error. In overall page reload

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2: Updating Grid-view using Pjax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777512/yii2-updating-grid-view-using-pjax)

Comment: Ok, I've flagged it as a duplicate, as it looks like this has already been answered on this site, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777512/yii2-updating-grid-view-using-pjax

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem a while ago and realized that when you call

```
$.pjax.reload({container:'#gridid'});
```

It reloads the whole page.

How i resolved this error is by :
If you are developing using google chrome inspect the grid and youll find that

```
your grid id has an added -pjax
```

So youll need to call

```
$.pjax.reload({container:'#gridid-pjax'});
in your case:
 $.pjax.reload({container:'#module-pjax'});
```