# Pjax reloads page on gridview search on Yii2

Tags: php, ajax, gridview, yii2, pjax

I'm loading a gridview inside a page with an ajax request.
Then, after the page is loaded, i want to let the user order and search as usual with gridview, obviously not reloading the page.

While the sorting works, the search reloads the page (and since the action loading the ajax content is different from the current one the page changes entirely). I know Pjax reloads the entire page after the timeout value, but that is not the problem as i changed to a really high value and i still get the reload.

Also, that is the only pjax on the page.

What could be the problem?

This is the code for the view with the gridview

```
    <?php Pjax::begin([
        "id" => "associates-ajax-list",
        "enablePushState" => FALSE,
        "enableReplaceState" => FALSE,
        "timeout" => 5000,
    ]); ?>

    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'name',
            'surname',

        ],
    ]); ?>
    <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
</div>
```

This is the code for the ajax action

```
public function actionAssociatesList($id) {
    $searchModel = new \app\models\AssociateSearch();
    $searchModel->associates_for = $id;
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        return $this->renderAjax('associates_list', [
                    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('associates_list', [
                    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The page where this content is loaded is a standard view page generated with Gii

Comment: You are sure the controller has both the order and search actions return JSON when needed? Yii2 is awesome by the way :)

Comment: The render function would take care of that, though...
Might be problem with pjax timeout setting? 
Check this older question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777512/yii2-updating-grid-view-using-pjax

Comment: @Brainfeeder yes, i'm quite sure the timeout is not the problem here. Changed it to a high value and even to false.
I'm not sure it returns JSON, but checking the documentation i don't think you have to specify that.

Comment: It has been a while since I used Yii2 and I might be mixing v1 and 2 ...
In browser console you see an ajax/pjax call when you try filtering?

Comment: And did you add some custom jquery/javascript code to trigger the search/filter?

Comment: No, there's no ajax/pjax call (checked binding an event with jquery).
No, didn't add any js.

Comment: Why does your search action is different from the action you use to load the gridview , ideally your search should point to the same action you used for loading the gridview via ajax for the first time, moreover i am unable to understand the problem you are highlighting regarding the `timeout`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam If you don't set a timeout everytime the pjax reload takes more than X milliseconds it reloads the page without ajax. But i already solved that, i just wanted to point out that was not the problem.
The action is the same for the gridview to be loaded and to be filtered. It's not the same as the original request from the user, obviously, since it's ajax and must be loaded from multiple actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the gridview. 
You need to specify an id. 
The funny thing is that this gridview was the only one generated for this page, so apparently there was no conflict.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'id' => "grid-view-name",
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
```

Comment: thats strange as the id is auto-generated if it isnt provided, with a single gridview it should be probably `w0`

Comment: The gridview id had to match the pjax id? Maybe when you leave them both out, it works with the auto-generated id's?

Comment: No, the pjax id and the grid view id can be different. And no, it doesn't work with both auto-generated.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with adding this script in the view?

```
<?php
    $this->registerJs(
       '$("document").ready(function(){ 
            $("#associates-ajax-list").on("pjax:end", function() {
                $.pjax.reload({container:"#associates-ajax-list"});  //Reload GridView
            });
        });'
    );
?>
```

You might need to alter some selectors since I don't know how the HTML looks like in your project.

AND you might need some JS to prevent the default submit action if the search fields are in a `<form>`. If not, the form will submit before the PJAX can trigger.

Comment: No, i tried it and i got the same result. There's no form in the page